# Voting script (PHP Handler, jQuery POST-sender) problem

Tags: php, jquery

Hai there.
I'm working on a voting script.
I'll just post a code first.
http://pastie.org/2014134 - php script
http://pastie.org/2014137 - jquery script (I'm just testing so it handles only "yes")
As you can see at the end of php code there are a couple of print();s, and it returns to the browser, as declared in jQuery script. Now about the problem: it returns "You didn't vote1dunno". But the choice data in POST query equaled "yes". 
What the hell? 
And also the php script just setting 3 for "yes", 5 for "dunno" and 4 for "no" in database. What the hell?

Comment: you need to use trim($_POST[id]) to remove the spaces

Comment: In the future it would be great if you could post your code on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error here:

`if ($choice = 'yes') {`

(and well as in other two conditions).

You should not use assigment operator `=` in your conditions but equality operator `==`:

`if ($choice == 'yes') {`

Answer (score 1):

stuken.yuri seems to have found the issue, but it's worth pointing out a few things: First of all you have a few SQL injects there, make sure ID is cast as an integer (if it is so) or run it through mysql_rea_escape_string(). Next you have a lot of duplicate code, i.e. stuff that is ran despite the value chosen.

Comment: lol my code is lame, I'll optimize it later, the main thing is that this code should work anyway.

Comment: And also there's something wrong with my sql queries. Nothing happens when I'm executing php script with a proper post data.

Answer (score 0):

You are using = for testing equality use == in code
So, if ($choice = 'no') should become if ($choice == 'no') likewise for all condition